# php mysql multiple if statements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

So I have this result array for which I need to run an IF statement and then display data depending on if it says yes or no, I got that part down, now I need to add another IF statement inside of the other one.. here is an example of what I am trying to do, I know it's wrong so please help.

```
if (isset($result_array)) {
    foreach ($result_array as $result) {
        if($result['hasChildren']=="yes") { ?>
            <center>
                <table class='kitTable' width='98%' border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='556587'>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='70%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['kitHeading'];?></td>
                        <td width='15%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['partHeading'];?></td>
                        <td width='15%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['qtyHeading'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $result['kitPart1'];?></td>
                        <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $result['childPart1'];?></td>
                        <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $result['childPartQTY1'];?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php if($result['kitPart2']=== NULL) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $result['kitPart2'];?></td>
                            <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $result['childPart2'];?></td>
                            <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $result['childPartQTY2'];?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>
            </center>
            <?php
        }
        elseif($result['hasChildren']=="no") {
            echo "";
        }               
    }
}
```

Here is my vardump

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(84) { 
        [0]=> string(2) "29" 
        ["id"]=> string(2) "29" 
        [1]=> string(6) "4004" 
        ["function"]=> string(6) "4004" 
        [2]=> string(30) "Mazda Car Part 4004" 
        ["name"]=> string(30) "Mazda Car Part 4004" 
        [3]=> string(3) "Stock" 
        ["stocktype"]=> string(3) "Stock" 
        [4]=> string(30) "http://i.imgur.com/default.png" 
        ["image"]=> string(30) "http://i.imgur.com/default.png" 
        [5]=> string(22) "mazda" 
        ["vendor"]=> string(22) "mazda" 
        [6]=> string(101) "mazda car part" 
        ["notes"]=> string(101) "mazda car part" 
        [7]=> string(12) "mazda" 
        ["oemproj"]=> string(12) "mazda" 
        [8]=> string(3) "yes" 
        ["hasChildren"]=> string(3) "yes" 
        [9]=> string(9) "Child Part" 
        ["partHeading"]=> string(9) "Child Part" 
        [10]=> string(28) "Child Parts Included with VP" 
        ["kitHeading"]=> string(28) "Child Parts Included with VP" 
        [11]=> string(3) "QTY" 
        ["qtyHeading"]=> string(3) "QTY" 
        [12]=> string(26) "mazda child part 1" 
        ["kitPart1"]=> string(26) "mazda child part 1" 
        [13]=> string(5) "1001" 
        ["childPart1"]=> string(5) "1001" 
        [14]=> string(1) "3" 
        ["childPartQTY1"]=> string(1) "3" 
        [15]=> string(42) "mazda car part 2" 
        ["kitPart2"]=> string(42) "mazda car part 2" 
        [16]=> string(5) "2002" 
        ["childPart2"]=> string(5) "2002" 
        [17]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["childPartQTY2"]=> string(1) "1" 
        [18]=> string(38) "" 
        ["kitPart3"]=> string(38) "" 
        [19]=> string(6) "" 
        ["childPart3"]=> string(6) "" 
        [20]=> string(1) "" 
        ["childPartQTY3"]=> string(1) "" 
        [21]=> string(0) "" 
        ["kitPart4"]=> string(0) "" 
        [22]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPart4"]=> string(0) "" 
        [23]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPartQTY4"]=> string(0) "" 
        [24]=> string(0) "" 
        ["kitPart5"]=> string(0) "" 
        [25]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPart5"]=> string(0) "" 
        [26]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPartQTY5"]=> string(0) "" 
        [27]=> string(0) "" 
        ["kitPart6"]=> string(0) "" 
        [28]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPart6"]=> string(0) "" 
        [29]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPartQTY6"]=> string(0) "" 
        [30]=> string(0) "" 
        ["kitPart7"]=> string(0) "" 
        [31]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPart7"]=> string(0) "" 
        [32]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPartQTY7"]=> string(0) "" 
        [33]=> string(0) "" 
        ["kitPart8"]=> string(0) "" 
        [34]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPart8"]=> string(0) "" 
        [35]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPartQTY8"]=> string(0) "" 
        [36]=> string(0) "" 
        ["kitPart9"]=> string(0) "" 
        [37]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPart9"]=> string(0) "" 
        [38]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPartQTY9"]=> string(0) "" 
        [39]=> string(0) "" 
        ["kitPart10"]=> string(0) "" 
        [40]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPart10"]=> string(0) "" 
        [41]=> string(0) "" 
        ["childPartQTY10"]=> string(0) "" 
    } 
}
```

Here is all of my PHP code with "Anonymous Man's" answer included:

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "part_lookup_tool";
$dbuser = "dbuser";
$dbpass = "dbpass";


global $part_lookup_tool_db;

$part_lookup_tool_db = new mysqli();
$part_lookup_tool_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$part_lookup_tool_db->set_charset("utf8");


if ($part_lookup_tool_db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $part_lookup_tool_db->connect_error);
    exit();
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$html = '';
$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<h1 class="btn2"><center> oemprojString</center></h1>';
$html .= '<h2><b style="background:#e4ee40; color:#000;">&nbsp; Part#: partidString &nbsp;</b></h2>';
$html .= '<h4><b>Stock Item Description:</b> partdescString</h4>';
$html .= '<h4><b>Stock Type:</b> stocktypeString</h4>';
$html .= '<h4><b>Vendor:</b> vendorString</h4>';
$html .= '</br>';
$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="imageString">';
$html .= '<center><img class="part" src="imageString" width="50%" height="50%"></center></a>';
$html .= '<h6>CLICK IMAGE TO ENLARGE</h6>';
$html .= '</br>';
$html .= '<h4><b>Notes:</b> notesString</h4>';
$html .= '</li>';


$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $part_lookup_tool_db->real_escape_string($search_string);


if (strlen($search_string) >= 3 && $search_string !== ' ') {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM parts WHERE partid LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR partdesc LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR stocktype LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR vendor LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR notes LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR oemproj LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';


        $result = $part_lookup_tool_db->query($query);
        while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $result_array[] = $results;
        }

        if (isset($result_array)) {
                foreach ($result_array as $result) {


$display_partid = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['partid']);
$display_partdesc = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['partdesc']);
$display_image = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "".$search_string."", $result['image']);
$display_stocktype = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['stocktype']);
$display_vendor = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['vendor']);
$display_notes = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['notes']);
$display_oemproj = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['oemproj']);


                        $output = str_replace('partdescString', $display_partdesc, $html);
                        $output = str_replace('partidString', $display_partid, $output);
                        $output = str_replace('imageString', $display_image, $output);
                        $output = str_replace('stocktypeString', $display_stocktype, $output);
                        $output = str_replace('vendorString', $display_vendor, $output);
                        $output = str_replace('notesString', $display_notes, $output);
                        $output = str_replace('oemprojString', $display_oemproj, $output);

                        echo($output);
                }
        }else{

                // ** I would rather just show that there were no results found overall **
                $output = str_replace('partdescString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $html);
                $output = str_replace('partidString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
                $output = str_replace('imageString', 'http://i.imgur.com/default', $output);
                $output = str_replace('stocktypeString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
                $output = str_replace('vendorString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
                $output = str_replace('notesString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
                $output = str_replace('oemprojString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);

                echo($output);
        }

        if (isset($result_array)) {
                foreach ($result_array as $result) {
                        $id = $result['id'];
                        //now query the children table for child parts
                        $stmt = $part_lookup_tool_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `children` WHERE `parentpartid` = :partid")
                        $stmt->bindParam(':partid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $stmt->execute;
                        if($children = $stmt->fetchAll() { ?>
                                <center>
                                        <table class='kitTable' width='98%' border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>
                                                <tr>
                                                        <td width='70%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['kitHeading'];?></td>
                                                        <td width='15%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['partHeading'];?></td>
                                                        <td width='15%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['qtyHeading'];?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php
                                                $i = 1;
                                                foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                        <td>Kit part <?php echo $i ;?></td>
                                                        <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $child['partid'];?></td>
                                                        <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $child['quantity'];?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php
                                                        $i++;
                                                } ?>
                                        </table>
                                </center>
                                <?php
                        }            
                }
        }

}
?>
```

Comment: whats wrong ?any error?

Comment: what do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: it's not showing any errors and there is data in the DB that should be shown, I also have this in my script to show errors;

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Still not seeing any errors..

and the border part isn't the problem it's the php =/

Thanks again..

Comment: @SeanD. tell use what you expected to happen with this code, and what is actually happening with this code... all you are telling us is something wrong, you need to tell us what is wrong, why is it wrong?

Comment: @geekynotsilly Alright so basically I have a MySQL DB with a bunch of car parts, but sometimes the part is a kit which has up to 10 more parts, I want to be able to list these "kit" parts only if they are in the DB, if they aren't I want nothing echoed.

Comment: @Arian there is data in the DB but it's not showing up, and there are no errors.

Comment: @SeanD. Do a `var_dump($result_array);` and edit your question, and post it in there...

Comment: Yes give us a var dump of the result, maybe we can code a for or foreach loop that will put all data to the table that is available.

Comment: Though I don't see any obvious errors there, that is not a very efficient way to go about it. Really, 'kitparts' should be a separate table, and a separate result set with 'id', 'childpart' etc. So for each id you have a separate result set you do a 'for each' on. This way you a) are not limited to 10 parts and b) don't have to output table rows for parts that don't exist. You may find that if you fix that, your problem goes away.

Comment: @AnonymousMan I understand what you saying, but I don't know how i would incorporate that in to my current code, could you help me out please?

Comment: Well this would involve redesigning your database first I'm afraid. It might be helpful if you post the db structure.

Comment: @AnonymousMan here is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7c5dc/1) to my SQLfiddle

Comment: @AnonymousMan Let me know if you need anything else, I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: I put together an answer below. Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is not properly normalized. You really need two tables.

```
table `Parts`

partid
function
name
stocktype
image
vendor
notes
oemproj

table `children`

partid (joined to partid in parts table)
parentpartid (this is the parts table partid of the kit)
quantity
```

You don't need any other data in `children` assuming all of those parts already exist in the other table. Now you can have from 1 to a zillion child parts in a kit without bloating the parts table.

Now your code would be more like this:

```
if (isset($result_array)) {
    foreach ($result_array as $result) {
        $id = $result['id'];
        //now query the children table for child parts (this assumes $con is your db connection
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Children` WHERE `parentpartid` = :partid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':partid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute;
        if($children = $stmt->fetchAll()) { ?>
            <center>
                <table class='kitTable' width='98%' border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='556587'>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='70%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['kitHeading'];?></td>
                        <td width='15%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['partHeading'];?></td>
                        <td width='15%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['qtyHeading'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Kit part <?php echo $i ;?></td>
                        <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $child['partid'];?></td>
                        <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $child['quantity'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        $i++;
                    } ?>
                </table>
            </center>
            <?php
        }             
    }
}
```

This should point you in the right direction. You might need to make some tweaks to get what you want. If you wanted to output more detail about the child parts you could run a more complex query and get the part name etc out of the parts table by joining on partid. This will likely solve your current problem, but more importantly, it will give you a lot more future flexibility with a normalized design.

Comment: Just did some edits to make that easier to read and included the $i++ which I forgot the first time.

Comment: thanks.. so I should be able to put this inline with my other `if (isset($result_array)) {` that is showing the other result information like image etc? or should I show you what I have for that because it looks like the code I am working on is not on your level (as in yours is way better) =/

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the image etc of the child parts?

Comment: No, right now I have a `if (isset($result_array)) {` above all of the code you came up with that shows all the other data from the DB like;

`id (which I need to change to 'partid' correct?)
function
name
stocktype
image
vendor
notes
oemproj`

what I wanted is some parts have children and some parts don't so I wanted to show that table for the main parts only if it has children..

Comment: Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/aa8id8UJ) to my entire PHP code, I'll also add this to the bottom of my question. -Kind Regards =)

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but I still need your help when you get a chance, thank you =)

Comment: Yes, this new code is occuring inside your $result_array loop. So as it goes through that loop it will check each item for child parts and display them if there are any. as for changing to 'partid', that is optional, i just like descriptive names, it makes the code easier to understand. I'll try to take a look at your full code tomorrow. Keep plugging away.

Comment: also just a heads up I am getting this error from your code:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'`

which is this line in your code:

`        if($children = $stmt->fetchAll() { ?>`

Thanks again,

Comment: oops, i left off the semicolon on the $con->prepare line. Fixed above.

Comment: yea I saw that and fixed it and now the error above is showing up =/

Comment: lol, also missed a close paren on that line after fetchAll. should be fetchAll())

Comment: ok fixed that now I'm getting this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object`

which corresponds with this line:  `$stmt->bindParam(':partid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

=/

Comment: I made some assumptions there that you were using PDO. You may not be. We're moving beyond the scope of your question here and these comments are a pain. How about sending that link to your full code to me at frumpus at yahoo dot com and I'll take a more detailed look tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I did find something wrong...

> Attribute "bordercolor" is not allowed on element "table".... you need to use CSS.

Comment: bordercolor was dropped in atleast HTML4 and moved to CSS

Comment: how did you know which html version he is using? :?